# How can I stop RubyMine/IntelliJ from closing my buffers?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

RubyMine 6.3.3 (which uses the IntelliJ codebase) seems to quietly close file buffers when I have ten files open and open another.  How can I disable or change this limit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> Editor -> Editor Tabs.
Under "Tab Closing Policy", set "Tab limit" to whatever you like. Use the maximum of 99 if you don't want tabs to auto-close at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Sorry for the delay.

Comment: RubyMine 7 has this setting under Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Editor Tabs. Not editing the actual answer since the question was originally for RubyMine 6.

Comment: Not a very intuitive setting, so thanks for pointing out that 99 is the maximum! Would've been nice of IntelliJ to point out that by itself in a tooltip, or offer a checkbox like eclipse does (where it defaults to not closing tabs). I first tried entering 0, or -1, but IntelliJ doesn't show an error message, just quietly reverts it back to 10 when you OK the settings dialog.

Comment: As of RubyMine 2021.3.2, 100 now seems to be the maximum value. I just tried to set a value greater than 100 and an error is displayed stating it must be between 1 and 100.