# How do I keep IntelliJ from closing my Editor Tabs automatically?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, intellij-15

When opening more than 10 Editor Tabs, IntelliJ automatically closes my least used Tab each time I open a new Tab.

How can I increase this limit?

More recent IntelliJ settings are accessed differently than older versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stop RubyMine/IntelliJ from closing my buffers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271631/how-can-i-stop-rubymine-intellij-from-closing-my-buffers)

Comment: Similar but I doubt anyone would find it compared to this question.

Comment: I was wondering, WHEN and why i closed some files. IntelliJ was closing stuff without asking. Stupid features sold as smart ones...

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Change the `Tab Limit` under the `Tab Closing Policy` settings.

Open your IntelliJ settings: Select `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Editor Tabs`.

Look for `Tab Closing Policy` -> `Tab Limit` and change the value to a higher integer.

You can also select to either close non-modified files first or less frequently used files first once your tab limit has been reached.

[image]

Comment: in Mac os, it's under Preferences -> Editor

Comment: Same will be applied to Android Studio for Mac, in version 3.3.1, select Preferences >Editor >Editor Tabs > Closing Policy section > Tab limit.

Comment: What a silly feature this is !!

Answer (score 6):

[If you need more than 100 tabs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Managing_Editor_Tabs.html#change-the-maximum-number-of-open-files):

> By default, the maximum number of open tabs that you can allow is
> limited to 100. If you want to increase that limit, press Ctrl+Shift+A
> or choose Help | Find Action from the main menu. In the popup that
> opens, start typing Registry, select the corresponding item and press
> Enter. In the Registry dialog, search for the ide.max.editor.tabs key
> and change its value.

Answer (score 5):

For recent versions on Mac, `Configure Editor tabs` is under [image]

In the Editor --> General --> `Editor Tabs`, Under `Closing Policy`, change the `Tab limit` as per your requirement

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding an answer to help anyone else with a similar problem.  OSX+Catalina on JetBrains/PyCharm was having closing all tabs when I lost focus on the application. When I came back the "Synchronization" action happened (top right circle arrow spins) and all windows are reset (many closed as a result). My fix was to disable  in the settings. Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Disable everything under the "Synchronization" section. You may need to seek out other "sync" options in settings.